# Configuring Gradle for multiple Android instrumentation test folders

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

I have two different types of instrumentation tests for my Android app, each of which require different instrumentation test runner classes.

I have been unable to find a clean way of encapsulating these test runners into a single class, and am now looking to separate these tests into two suites each with its own instrumentation test runner.

Is it possible to create another test folder alongside `androidTest`, and how can this be configured within my `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new folder on the same level as `test` and `androidTest`
(e.g.: I created one called `acceptanceTest`).

Then, in your module's build.gradle file include this outside the `android { }` block:

```
android.sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/acceptanceTest"
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to run instrumented tests on this new folder too.

PS.: If you want a folder accessible by both `androidTest` and `test` folders (say, a test fixtures folder called `testShared`), do the same process but also include a `test { }` block there:

```
android.sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShared"
    }

    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShared"
    }
}
```