# Run all UI/Unit tests from a multi-module project using a single command

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We have a multi-module Android project, in which some modules contain UI tests and some contain Unit tests. We wish to run all UI tests from all modules using a single Gradle command and do the same thing for Unit tests.

The only way that we found to do this was with the following config inside the main `app` module that implements all the other sub-modules (basically make the `app` module know about all the other `androidTest` and `test` folders in the project):

**app/build.gradle:**

```
 sourceSets {
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += ["${project(':feature-login').projectDir}/src/androidTest/java"]
        test.java.srcDirs += ["${project(':feature-login').projectDir}/src/test/java"]
        test.java.srcDirs += ["${project(':core').projectDir}/src/test/java"]
    }
```

Then we run the following Gradle commands:

```
./gradlew app:connectedDemoDebugAndroidTest
./gradlew app:testDemoDebugUnitTest
```

**Question:** Is there a better/simpler way to achieve this? Or is there a way to add the `androidTest` and `test` folders from the above solution dynamically (using a relative path), instead of having to write the `srcDirs` line for each and every module (we have 40+ modules)?

Comment: This article may be useful, but it's similar to what you already have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623730/configuring-gradle-for-multiple-android-instrumentation-test-folders

Answer (score -3):

just run in terminal:

./gradlew test

Please, [see docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line) for more options